# Redirect error SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I am using a simple redirect operation after writing some data into data extension

```
function main() {
    try {
        var response = processGoogleCaptcha();
        var captcha = new CaptchaResponse(response.success);
        if (captcha.success == true) {
            // writeFormData('Register_interest');
            Redirect("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/xxxx/", true);
        } else {
            var error_result = "Google Captcha auth failed!";
            sendMessage(error_result);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        var error = Platform.Function.Stringify(e);
        sendMessage(error);
        Redirect("https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/xxxx/", true);
    }
}
main();
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Error in the application.",
    "description": "ExactTarget.OMM.AMPScriptRedirectException: Error in the application. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"
}
```

I am not using a single line of AMPScript in my code.

Does anyone know what the error could be from?

Comment: can you give the full context? I believe @Rain might be right and its as simple as not loading the Core library

Comment: I am loading Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1"); at the top of my script properly but I use a set of function to do some stuff and then I call them out in the "main" function. Redirect to error page works good. Edited the question to give more context

Comment: Have you verified it works without the Redirects listed? I get the feeling the error resides inside the syntax of your other code or similar issue in one of your other functions - if the page loads fine and you declared the core library.

Comment: Very good point @Gortonington - Redirect works just find on it's own... Seems the problem lies within one of other functions. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you referencing to these CloudPages? If it's via `CloudPagesURL`, then this would be AMPscript. Also make sure the CloudPages are available in the same BU.

Additionally, double check that you have the proper syntax in place, including loading the core library:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

try {
    Redirect("http://page1.com",true);
 } 
 catch(e) {
    Redirect("http://page2.com",true);
} 
 </script>
```